# Can I repair my helicopter ?

Tags: just-cause-3

I enjoy flying in Just Cause 3 so I want to keep my helicopter for as long as I can through fire fights.   Is there anyway or anywhere I can go to repair my helicopter ?

This is especially helpful when I run out of beacons or am on a cool down for calling in attack choppers.

Comment: There are upgrades to reduce the beacon air vehicle timeout, to eventually zero, if you get enough Gears from the Challenges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to repair any vehicle in Just Cause 3. It is unknown if this will be a feature in a future patch.